# BM-25 search algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am designing a okapi bm25 based search engine in python what should I use to store page data(relevance etc.) and tf,idf for fast access? Is python shelf good enough for a scalable design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you have a look at [wiredtiger](http://source.wiredtiger.com/) it's powerful keyvalue store, faster than leveldb or bsddb (the shelf module use bsddb), to build your storage. They are different pattern revelant here you can look stackoverflow for questions regarding leveldb or [bsddb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bsddb).

If you are new to key/value stores I recommend you use [leveldb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=leveldb) with [plyvel](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plyvel) which is a good start but doesn't scale as well as wiredtiger.